# Checking Results in Functional Tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automated-tests

I have created a library which communicates with a device and provides high-level APIs to user.

Now I am trying to create functional tests - tests that communicates with the real device.

**Question**: Is it OK to check results using own functions? For example there are methods GetChannelState() and SetChannelState(). Can I check 'Get' method with a help of 'Set' method and vice versa? Please describe an approach you use in similar cases.

**Example**:
There is oscilloscope. To turn its second channel ON, the library sends to the oscilloscope string `"SELECT:CH2 ON"`. To check whether the channel is on, it sends `"SELECT?"` then parses the response. The response will look similar to following `"SELECT:CH1 1;CH2 1;CH3 0;CH4 0"`.

To set a value there is `SetChannelState(int channelNumber)` API, and get a value there is `GetChannelState(int channelNumber)` API.

So the question is whether I can use SetChannelState to test GetChannelState and vise versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - as long as you completed few tests proving that your set indeed sets whatever it was given (or obeys the rules you wanted it to). In case your setting logic is simple there might be no practical usage of that one, though growing complexity has to be tested before the rest of a code depdendent upon this bit.

However there are edge cases. You might want to mock your set logic with a dummy one and just ensure that it indeed was invoked, lets say, exactly once. The same applies to both get and set behaviors. Those are independent and shouldn't rely on realworld implementation.

When it's done, you have all power to trust your own code and use it in your functional tests without any doubts.